# Pass parameter to hooked function using custom page template

Tags: functions, hooks, page-template, deprecation

Based upon [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97564/display-products-from-specific-category-in-shop-page) I have tried to write the following code as:

**Custom Page template:**

```
    /*
 Template Name: product_filter
     */
    get_header();
    do_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'COOLING');
```

**Functions.php**

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','shop_filter_cat',10,1);

 function shop_filter_cat($query, $arg) {
    if (!is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) && $query->is_main_query()) {
       $query->set('tax_query', array(
                    array ('taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                       'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => $arg
                                 )
                     )
       );   
    }
 }
```

But I have got following warning:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for shop_filter_cat(), called in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 600 and
>   defined in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\storefront\functions.php
>   on line 56

and error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_main_query()
>   on string in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-deprecated-functions.php:677
>   Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(524):
>   wc_shop_order_status_backwards_compatibility('COOLING') #1
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\storefront\testing.php(6):
>   do_action('pre_get_posts', 'COOLING') #2
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template-loader.php(75):
>   include('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #3
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php(19):
>   require_once('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #4
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php(17):
>   require('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #5 {main} thrown in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-deprecated-functions.php
>   on line 677

Answer (score 3):

you make a mistake in the call of `add_action`
the last parameters must be changed from 1 to 2

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','shop_filter_cat',10,2);
```

Comment: the `do_action` is probably not needed as well

Comment: ok, it removed warning and what about error

Comment: MuhammadMuazzam: I think @MarkKaplun already answered that for you regarding the error, since you're using string as an input argument.  There's also no second input argument for pre_get_posts by default.

Comment: do_action is being used to change parameter value when custom page input field value change that I will do as well. so when I have tried to change it as do_action( 'pre_get_posts', '','COOLING'); it still have error

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam This is not the way to pass on data to the main query, since you're overriding the query object with a string value (hence the error) and the main query has already been activated when you are inside  the template file.

Comment: @birgire what other way to fulfill the requirement of changing product category from page template. Please not this action is being performed from page template if remove parameters.